# Easier famility of graphs for MAXCUT

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, max-flow-min-cut, max-cut

I would like to know if there are particular family of graphs for which the Goemans-Williamson MAXCUT Approximation Algorithm renders higher than 0.878 approximation ratio. TIA

Comment: My guess is that OP meant to say "better" instead of "lower".

Comment: @ChandraChekuri In that case, those would be an *easy* family for the algorithm, not the *hardest*, right?

Comment: I think the OP means something like, "Is there an interesting family of graphs $\mathcal{F}$ on which MAX-CUT is known to be NP-hard and such that Goemans-Williamson restricted to graphs in $\mathcal{F}$ achieves an approximation factor of, say, $0.91$? This seems like a good question, although, as Emil notes, it's inconsistent with the title.

Comment: I don’t think this guessing game is going to get anywhere. The OP needs to make the question clear.

Comment: @NealYoung, I have replaced "lower" with "higher". My sincere apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri, ^

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, ^

Comment: @HuckBennett, ^

Comment: @NealYoung, done. Thanks a lot for catching it.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://doi.org/10.1016/S0196-6774(02)00005-6

Comment: I'm deleting my earlier comments as they no longer apply to the corrected post.  Hopefully you'll get enough re-open votes, but if not you could consider posting the question as a new post.